# <!CDATA[]]]> not working when shifted from strings.xml to MainActivity.xml

Tags: android, exoplayer, cdata

I was working on exoplayer example by google code labs. The issue is when I'm loading a link from string.xml it works.

**string.xml**

```
<string name="media_url_dash"><![CDATA[http://www.youtube.com/api/manifest/dash/id/bf5bb2419360daf1/source/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=51AF5F39AB0CEC3E5497CD9C900EBFEAECCCB5C7.8506521BFC350652163895D4C26DEE124209AA9E&key=ik0]]></string>
```

I convert the above string to uri and run the uri to buffer video successfully like this.

**VideoActivity.java**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.media_url_dash));
```

But when I try the same thing using java file the link do not works.

**Error Case**

```
String url = "<![CDATA[http://www.youtube.com/api/manifest/dash/id/bf5bb2419360daf1/source/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=51AF5F39AB0CEC3E5497CD9C900EBFEAECCCB5C7.8506521BFC350652163895D4C26DEE124209AA9E&key=ik0]]>";
uri = Uri.parse(url);
```

I want to do this to run my url dynamically from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CDATA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) is a feature of XML. When not using XML, don't use CDATA. Remove the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` from your string literal.

Comment: Im using firebase as my server can you tell me which format the video must be saved there. As much I searched it should be MPD which supports adaptive streaming.